# Excel VBA - Pass list as function parameter

Tags: excel, vba

With some functions, you can do something like `=SEARCH({"some","thing"},A1)`

How could I write a function that accepts a parameter like `{"some","thing"}`?

I tried `Function whatever(my_list as Variant)` and `Function whatever(my_list() as Variant)` based on some other answers/sites I've seen, but it wasn't working and I'm not sure why.

I think the above would work if my function was something like `=WHATEVER("some","thing")` but I would want additional parameters, like `=WHATEVER(A1,{"some","thing"},0,B1)`

I would want to loop through the list after accepting it as a parameter. Thank you!

Comment: That is exactly what the `ParamArray` argument is for.

Comment: What are the benefits of using `ParamArray` over the answer provided by ThunderFrame?

Comment: It is quite a bit more flexible in what it can pass. Both [Tushar Mehta](http://www.tushar-mehta.com/publish_train/xl_vba_cases/1005%20ParamArray.shtml) and [Chip Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/OptionalArgumentsToProcedures.aspx) have some good discussions about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a function like:

```
Public Function Foo(values As Variant) As String
  Dim i As Long
  For i = LBound(values) To UBound(values)
    Foo = Foo & values(i)
  Next i
End Function
```

And then use it in an Excel formulas like so:

```
=Foo({"a","b","c"})
```

Which will return a cell value of `abc`.

**EDIT....**

But that function won't handle 2 dimensional arrays like `=Foo({"a","b","c";"d","e","f"})` or passing a Range to the function, like `=Foo(A1:B6)`.

This is a bit more robust:

```
Public Function Foo(ByVal values As Variant) As String

  Dim temp As Variant
  temp = values

  Dim i As Long
  Dim j As Long
  Dim is2D As Boolean

  If IsArray(temp) Then
    On Error Resume Next
    is2D = IsNumeric(LBound(temp, 2))
    On Error GoTo 0

    If is2D Then
      For i = LBound(temp, 1) To UBound(temp, 1)
        For j = LBound(temp, 2) To UBound(temp, 2)
          Foo = Foo & temp(i, j)
        Next j
      Next i
    Else
      For i = LBound(temp) To UBound(temp)
        Foo = Foo & temp(i)
      Next i
    End If
  Else
    Foo = temp
  End If

End Function
```

Comment: Nice alternative to `ParamArray`

Comment: What are the pros/cons of this over `ParamArray`? If I were to use `ParamArray` could I pass in only a single item rather than a list? For example, `SEARCH` can be used like `=SEARCH("this",A1)` or `=SEARCH({"this"},A1)`, but currently, using this answer, my function can only accept the latter version. This may be a topic for a separate question.

Comment: ParamArray needs to be the *last* argument in the function (and so there can only be one ParamArray parameter), and you can't pass an array (like `=Foo({"a","b","c"})', but instead you'd call `Foo("a","b","c")`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to declaring the parameter as `Variant`, [`IsArray`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/isarray-function) can be used to check if the parameter is array, and `For Each` can be used instead of `For` if the number of dimensions is not known:

```
Public Function MySearch(values, value) As Boolean

    If TypeOf values Is Excel.Range Then values = values  ' convert Range to array or value

    If TypeOf value  Is Excel.Range Then value  = value   ' not sure if this is needed ..

    If Not IsArray(values) Then MySearch = values = value : Exit Function

    Dim v    ' As Variant by default

    For Each v In values
        If v = value Then MySearch = True : Exit Function
    Next i

    MySearch = False
End Function
```

Comment: What happens if values is a 1-cell range?

Comment: @ThunderFrame then it's not array :]. I didn't test it but should be ok for most possible types